Kubernetes RBAC - allow management of specific CRDs with resourceNames ClusterRole rules condition
Question: How can I narrow access to specific named customresourcedefinitions using resourceNames?
I am trying to grant a cluster user access to create/update/delete customresourcedefinitions. Using this ClusterRole, the user can create/update/delete their desired CRD:
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: example
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - apiextensions.k8s.io
  resources:
  - customresourcedefinitions
  verbs:
  - '*'

I'd like to restrict their access to only managing specific CRDs. This updated ClusterRole is denied from creating the named CRD example.acme.com:
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: example
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - apiextensions.k8s.io
  resourceNames:
  - example.acme.com
  resources:
  - customresourcedefinitions
  verbs:
  - '*'

Error message user receives (user is attempting to deploy crd using helmfile, cluster is amazon eks 1.30.4):
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io is forbidden: User "arn:aws....:assumed-role/..../i-aaaaaaa" cannot create resource "customresourcedefinitions" in API group "apiextensions.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
Question: How can I narrow access to specific named customresourcedefinitions using resourceNames?

Well this is not strictly possible with RBAC from the docs :(

Note: You cannot restrict create or deletecollection requests by their resource name. For create, this limitation is because the name of the new object may not be known at authorization time. If you restrict list or watch by resourceName, clients must include a metadata.name field selector in their list or watch request that matches the specified resourceName in order to be authorized. For example, kubectl get configmaps --field-selector=metadata.name=my-configmap

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources
I will try allowing create for any resource name, but restricting other verbs with resourceNames
